# Laravel, update field after ajax post

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am making a small like system. I already succeeded to make an ajax post to my database, where I increase the tblarticles with `row.like` with 1. Now on the same page where I am making the ajax post, I want to update the value of the field after every ajax post. Now my problem is that i need to refresh, before seeing 1 instead of the standard 0

Ajax post

```
$.ajax({
    url:"articles" ,
    type: "post",
    data: {
        'user_id':userid[0].value,
        'article_id':articleid[0].value,
        'user_id_fk':useridarticle[0].value,
        '_token': token[0].value
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

view `article/index.blade.php`

```
@foreach($articles as $article)

          <div class="work-container">
              <article class="work-item">
                  <a href="{{action('HomeController@showArticle', [$article->id, $article->title])}}" class="work-thumbnail">
                      <img src="/articlePics/{{$article->image}}" alt="work-item">
                  </a>
                  <div class="work-info">
                      <span class="user">{{$article->title}}</span>
                      <div class="actions">
                          <form id="actionForm" action="" method="post" role="form">
                              <input type="hidden" name="articleId" value="{{$article->id}}">
                              <input type="hidden" name="userIdFk" value="{{$article->user_id}}">
                              <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="{{Auth::id()}}">
                              <input type="submit" name="like" class="likeBtn" id="test" value="Like">
                              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
                          </form>
                          <span class="likes" name="currentLikes">{{$article->likes}}</span>
                      </div>

                  </div>
              </article>
          </div>
      @endforeach
```

Controller

```
if(Request::ajax()) {
        $data = Input::all();
        $user_id =  Auth::id();
        $article_id = Input::get('article_id');
        $user_id_fk = Input::get('user_id_fk');
        $results = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND article_id = '$article_id'") );
        $likedOrNot = DB::table('likes')
                ->where('article_id', $article_id)
                ->where('user_id', $user_id)
                ->pluck('likes');

        $currentLikesDB = DB::table('articles')->where('id', $article_id)->pluck('likes');
        echo json_encode(['likesnumber' => $currentLikesDB]);
```

It is the last span I want to change with the current data posted after the ajax post.

Comment: You need to pass an encoded value of the `counted currentLikes` and then simply within your `success:function(data)` you can access it like as `$('.likes').text('data.name_of_field_you_passed')`

Comment: Don't just echo from your controller. You need to set your headers. The correct way in Laravel would be `return Response::json(['likesnumber' => $currentLikesDB]);`

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Response::json()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

in the `articles` echo the like number with `json_encode`.

```
$currentLikesDB = DB::table('likes')->where('article_id', $article_id)->first();
$likesnumber = $currentLikesDB->likes;
return json_encode(['likesnumber' => $likesnumber]);
```

then ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"articles" ,
    type: "post",
    data: {
        'user_id':userid[0].value,
        'article_id':articleid[0].value,
        'user_id_fk':useridarticle[0].value,
        '_token': token[0].value
    },
    success: function(data){
        $('.likes').html(data.likesnumber);
    }
});
```

Comment: likesnumber is not recognized, this is what I added in my controller $currentLikesDB= DB::table('likes')
                ->where('article_id', $article_id)
                ->pluck('likes');
            echo json_encode(['likesnumber' => $currentLikesDB]);

Comment: still the same... It als gives this in my editor _unresolved variable likesnumber_

Comment: please console log the data after success: console.log(data);

what do you get back?

Comment: POST http://revise.dev/articles 500 (Internal Server Error) , And on the Network tab _Call to undefined method stdClass::pluck()_

Comment: Then don't use the pluck() method. Edited my answer.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

Comment: Replace echo please. Edited

Comment: var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data); keeps being a problem. *sigh*

Comment: what do you get back in data? please show me the console.log

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token on.parseJSON @ jquery.min.js:4$.ajax.success @ scripts.js:67j @ jquery.min.js:2k.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2x @ jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:4  when clicking: _var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);_

Comment: Got it. My data is already an object. No need to parse it. The javascript interpreter has already parsed it for me. ! thank you so much

Comment: @SaraBarreraRiano don't forget to mark the correct answer here on stackoverflow so that others can solve similar problems as well

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, after doing requires task, fire a query to get the counts.

Echo then in `json_encode()`.

In ajax `success()`, you can use parse the data and add where ever you want.

If you want to fetch only one value, no need of `json_encode()`.

Directly echo the value and use in ajax `success()`

Answer (score 0):

in your ajax request, return the total counts as a JSON and in you ajax's success function write this

```
success: function(data){
$('.likes').html(data.likesCount);
    }
```